# Creating Postgis Polygon using ST_ConcaveHull from Geometry Points

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgis 2.2 table with 20 columns of type `geometry(Point,4326)`

I'd like to generate a polygon which covers the outer boundary of the points - it seems like [ST_ConcaveHull](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ConcaveHull.html) is a good option, but I can't see how to do it without first converting my points back to text (which seems to be missing the point).

Is st_concavehull the right option, and how do I go about constructing the query?

Thanks!

Comment: Have now moved this question to the GIS forum: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218849/creating-postgis-polygon-using-st-concavehull-from-geometry-points

Answer (score 2):

You first need to collect your points, then pass this collection to ST_ConcaveHull:

```
ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(geom), 1)
```

Per the [ST_ConcaveHull documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ConcaveHull.html):

> Although it is not an aggregate - you can use it in conjunction with ST_Collect or ST_Union to get the concave hull of a set of points/linestring/polygons ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(somepointfield), 0.80).

Comment: great - it was st_collect that i was missing. thanks